# Testing Inside .each() and breaking out

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

What I'm trying to do here is loop through a list of images with jquery .each() and test if the src that I'm passing to the function already exists inside the list. If it doesn't I want to add it, if does I don't want to do anything. Where do I put the code to add a new image baring in mind I only want to do this after the each() iterations are over

Here's what I have so far

```
function addFriendImage(imageSrc){ //Adds the image of the friend to the sidebar

    var imgReturn = $('ul.friendImages li img').each(function(){
        var currentImageSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        if(currentImageSrc == imageSrc){
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(imgReturn != false){//does this make sense?
        //I'll add an new image, (I can work out to do this bit myself)
    }
}
```

I'm new to javascript and jquery so I may have gone wrong with the syntax. 
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the loop and just find all images with the src attribute you're looking for, using the jQuery [`[attribute="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
function addFriendImage(imageSrc){ //Adds the image of the friend to the sidebar

    if ($('ul.friendImages li img[src="' + imageSrc + '"]').length) {
       // img with src attribute matching imageSrc exists
    } else {
       // img doesn't exist
    }

}
```

You can't return values from `$.each` as it always returns the jQuery object for call chaining. However, returning true/false does have special meaning: Returning `false` behaves like a `break;` statement and iteration stops, while returning `true` behaves like a `continue` statement, stopping the current iteration early and continuing to the next.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution but most of all for the explanation. I tend to overcomplicate my code. I suppose that's part of the learning process.

Comment: No problem. Learning to supplement your JavaScript with jQuery isn't hard. Learning to use jQuery *correctly* takes time.

Comment: Sorry just noticed. Can you please tell me what the .length method is for? Can the if not be true without it?

Comment: @will $('selector') always returns a jQuery object, wrapping 0 or more actual DOM elements. You need `.length` to return the number of elements match. If `.length` returns 0, it evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all the extra stuff and query it directly.

```
if(!($('ul.friendImages li img[src=' + imageSrc + ']').length)){
}
```